# How can I use this react-hook function in my code?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, aws-amplify

I am trying to customize my Amplify UI... I am not sure how to proceed. I am trying to use this custom function in my code:

```
    import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';



export default class SignupPage extends Component {
  handleSignUp = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const{username, email, password, phone_number} = this.props.inputs;
    Auth.signUp({
      username,
      password,
      attributes:{
        email,
        phone_number
      },
      validationData: []
    })
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .then(()=>this.props.switchComponent("Verify"))
      .catc(err => console.log(err))
    };
}

function SignupPage() {
  const [firstFocus, setFirstFocus] = React.useState(false);
  const [lastFocus, setLastFocus] = React.useState(false);
  const [emailFocus, setEmailFocus] = React.useState(false);
  const [passwordFocus, setPasswordFocus] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.add("signup-page");
    document.body.classList.add("sidebar-collapse");
    document.documentElement.classList.remove("nav-open");
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    return function cleanup() {
      document.body.classList.remove("signup-page");
      document.body.classList.remove("sidebar-collapse");
    };

  }, []);
```

but I keep getting this error:
[image: issue with code]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the error updated? Because it says `SignupPage` has allready been declared but in your code there is just one and the other is `Signup `

Comment: Most probably your auth.signup giving your this trouble

Comment: woops @Girgetto I need to correct that thanks, code is corrected

Comment: Ok, so as the error is describing you have declared two times `SignupPage`, if you need to use the function component then you need to remove the class component

Comment: I guess I will have to, but can I still use the handle function as well ? I am really new to React

Comment: when I bumped the export to the end of the code, I can't use that HandleSignup function that it at the top of the time... I need to figure out how to get that done....

Comment: I see, maybe this example can help you https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-fast-ujve7?file=/src/App.js, I've moved the `handleSignUp` into the functional component. It should work without errors if these two variable `inputs`, `switchComponent` are passed into `SignupPage` component something like this `<SignupPage inputs={inputs} switchComponent={switchComponent} />`

Comment: @Girgetto thanks dude! Super helpful... looks like that got it working! yay!